# Utilizing prior information about many different coins in a Beta distribution for a coin

Tags: prior, beta-distribution

I have prior information about the outcomes of tossing different coins in the form of "$a_i$ heads and $b_i$ tails" records. I do not have the true probabilities/ratios, but for some records the number of tosses is high, so the ratios are quite localized in those cases. I see that coins seem to have different probabilities. I also see that the coins are heavily biased towards 0.

I want to utilize this prior information to make a Beta distribution for the heads probability of a coin for which I saw $A$ heads and $B$ tails.

**How can I utilize that prior information properly?**

I could just add $\sum{a_i}$ to $A$ and $\sum{b_i}$ to $B$, but that does not feel right as the "strength" of such prior is too high and it grows too fast if I start getting more prior knowledge. Normalizing that so that the sum equals 1 seems too weak.

My current idea is to normalize by the score sums by the number of prior records I have: to add $\sum^n_{i=1}{a_i}/n$ to $A$ and $\sum^n_{i=1}{b_i}/n$ to $B$.

P.S. The real world task behind this is as follows:

I have data about how users click on some items on the Web. For each item I have $numClicks_i$ and $numViews_i$. I want to prune the data retaining only the items for which I have the most *information* about their CTR (click-through rate) - $numClicks_i/numViews_i$. I tried to use the width of the Beta distribution's 80% confidence interval as the measure of [lack of] information. But I need a proper non-symmetrical prior. 1 click is more important than 100 non-clicks as clicks are very rare.

Comment: These are different coins, each of this has a separate heads probability; and the beta distribution would be over heads probability?  Why not consider the observed counts as data and infer the parameters of the beta distribution?

Comment: Is it a possibility that all coins really have the same probability? In such case you could first make a test for homogeneity.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala The coins are different. Each has it's own probability. But I notice that it's heavily biased towards 0 (e.g. < 0.01) for the coins with lots of data. If I use some uninformed prior for a coin in question, the posterior would be very wrong since it would be symmetrical.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen No, I'm sure the coins have different probabilities. But the distribution of those probabilities seems to be heavily biased towards 0. I want to utilize that knowledge.